# Error actualizando programa mediante Request y Github con Python

Tags: python, windows, github, python-requests, zip

Estoy tratando de usar Github mediante un Release para poder actualiar mi app en Python, cada que hay una version nueva, sin embargo al momento de realizar la descarga de la update todo funciona bien, pero al momento de reemplazar la carpeta con la actualizacion por la carpeta actual llamada "data" me sale el siguiente error:

```
 File "c:\Users\Thomas Esteban\Escritorio\revisionActuacionesSinInterfaz\data\main.py", 
line 326, in main
    actualizacionDeLaApp.check_update()
  File "c:\Users\Thomas Esteban\Escritorio\revisionActuacionesSinInterfaz\data\actualizacionDeLaApp.py", line 43, in check_update
    os.replace(filename, "revisionDeActuacionesConsola-1.1.0")
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado: 'data' -> 'revisionDeActuacionesConsola-1.1.0'
```

Cabe recalcar que la carpeta data tiene todos los permisos que le puedo asginar en mi usuairo, adjunto pantallazo

[image: Aqui el ss de los permisos de la carpeta data]

el codigo con la funcion encargada de hacer la actualización es el siguiente:

```
import os
import requests
import zipfile

def check_update():
    # Obtener la versión actual de la aplicación
    current_version = "1.0.0"

    # Obtener la versión de la actualización disponible
    response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/thomasesteban22/revisionDeActuacionesConsola/releases/latest").json()
    available_version = response.get("tag_name")

    # Si la versión disponible es superior a la versión actual, descargar la actualización
    if available_version is not None and available_version > current_version:
        # Descargar el archivo de actualización
        update_url = "https://github.com/thomasesteban22/revisionDeActuacionesConsola/archive/refs/tags/" + available_version + ".zip"

        # Verificar si el archivo de actualización existe
        head_response = requests.head(update_url)
        if head_response.status_code == 404:
            print("El archivo de actualización no existe.")
            return

        # Guardar el archivo de actualización en el disco como un archivo binario
        with open("update.zip", "wb") as f:
            f.write(requests.get(update_url).content)

        # Try to unzip the update file
        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile("update.zip", "r") as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error al descargar o descomprimir la actualización:", e)
            return

        # Instalar la actualización
        print("¿Desea instalar la actualización? (s/n)")
        answer = input()
        if answer == "s":
            # Reemplazar el código actual por el código nuevo
            filename = os.path.basename("data")
            if os.path.exists(filename):
                os.replace(filename, "revisionDeActuacionesConsola-1.1.0")
            else:
                print("El archivo 'revisionActuacionesSinInterfaz' no existe.")
    else:
        print("No hay actualizaciones disponibles.")
```

Mi main() simplemente ejecuta la función

Gracias y que tengan buen dia